# Tags on Meta.SE sometimes showing up wrong

Tags: bug, design, meta

It seems that from time to time, some tags on Meta.SE can be displayed with the wrong styling.

Screenshot from the [moderator-tags](/questions/tagged/moderator-tags) wiki that highlights this effect:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a reason for this?

Screenshot from Safari, using iOS 10.1.1.

Comment: Tag-wiki pages seem to not be getting the styling for these tags that other pages get.  The usual styling sets visited and unvisited link colors to be the same.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've seen this in normal posts too.

Comment: Makes sense; tag wikis are just posts under the covers.  Do you happen to have a link to a regular post where this happens?  (I assume it's consistent across all posts.)